# Wordpress Galleries Crash

Tags: wordpress

I am using TN3Gallery on my wordpress. As soon as I enable Nivo Slider TN3Gallery stops working. I couldn't find any solution for this problem. I don't think wordpress lets you disable specific plugins on a page basis. How can I fix this issue ?

TN3Gallery Page; http://goo.gl/UZpza

Comment: you might have a simple jquery conflict . can you enable the error on the page so we could check it (WITH the error ?? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `wordpress` `Conditional Tags` in your theme if you want to disable plugin at certain pages/posts. following link may be helpful to you -

1. [Link For Conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)
2. [Discussion Board Link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-front-end-editor-disable-on-specific-pages)
3. [Simple Example](http://scribu.net/wordpress/front-end-editor/loading-only-on-certain-pages.html)